# Saving Arrays in Swift

Tags: serialization, swift, save

I have a question about saving Arrays in Apple's new programming language Swift. In Objective-C I saved data with `NSFileManager`... but this doesn't work anymore in Swift. So I wanted to ask how I should save an array WITHOUT using NSUserDefaults which isn't really suited for storing a big amount of data. I would really much appreciate any help :]

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work"? What exactly isn't working? If you rewrite your Objective-C code in Swift, it should work in exactly the same way.

Comment: The class reference for NSFileManager shows Swift versions of the methods, so Apple seems to think it works.

Comment: They both use exactly the same runtime and call exactly the same functions under the hood, so there's no reason for it to not work.

Comment: It actually starts with the first line of my Objective-C code when I want to find a path where I can store my data: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); is the code in Objective-C but NSDocumentDirectory isn't available in Swift. @ScottHunter could you give me a link to the class reference?

Comment: well I figured out the problem from the comment above but what do I have to do with this Objective-C line?: 
    NSMutableDictionary *rootObject;
    rootObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; couldn't someone tell me how to save data with all the code required?

Comment: Google NSFileManager; its the top hit.

Answer (score 2):

First (if your array is not of string type) change it to String:

```
var notStringArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var array: [String] = []

for value in notStringArray{
    array.append(String(value))
}
```

Then reduce the array to one string:

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] //Ignore this line if your array wasn't of type String and you did the step above
var stringFromArray = reduce(array, "") { $0.isEmpty ? $1 : "\($0)\n\($1)" }
```

This create an string that looks like this:

```
"1
 2
 3
 4
 5"
```

And then to write and read a file add this class at the top of your file:

```
class File {
    class func open (path: String, utf8: NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding) -> String? {
        var error: NSError?   // 
        return NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) ? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: utf8, error: &error)! : nil
    }
    class func save (path: String, fileContent: String, utf8: NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding) -> Bool {
        var error: NSError?   // 
        return fileContent.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: utf8, error: &error)
    }

}
```

(Don't forget to import UIKit)

To save to a file:

```
let didSave = File.save("DirectoryOfFile", content: stringFromArray) 
if didSave {
    println("file saved") 
} else {
    println("error saving file") 
}
```

To get it back:

```
var stringFromFile = ""

if let loadData = File.open("DirectoryOfFile") {
    stringFromFile = loadData
} else {
    println("error reading file")
}
```

To put it back in an array:

```
var newArray: [String] = [] //Creates empty string array
newArray = stringFromFile.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

And there you have it

Comment: Show me your class in your question please. Iv'e added in my question what to do if your array isn't of type String

Comment: Probably i found it on the internet

Comment: I am glad you liked it, I have also created the same for urls instead of paths